# Zookeeper in AWS VPC - This ZooKeeper instance is not currently serving requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-zookeeper, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to setup a Mesos cluster in AWS VPC.
I've setup 3 Ubuntu machines with Mesos according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-production-ready-mesosphere-cluster-on-ubuntu-14-04).

The problem is inside the web UI I see a message `No master is currently leading ...` and when I ssh to any of the 3 master machines and run `echo srvr | nc localhost 2182` I get `This ZooKeeper instance is not currently serving requests` on all of them.

I also can't ping between the 3 servers.

Comment: Are those 3 instance in Private subnet or a public subnet?

Comment: The subnet has Auto-assign `Public IP:yes`

Comment: Run this command from one of the server telnet localhost 2182